# Write Ahead Cache causes CacheWriterException

Tags: ignite

I was trying to do some simple benchmarking (using JMH) of an ignite cache with Write Ahead enabled.
Write-Through is working fine, however write-ahead errors out.

I'm getting `CacheWriterException` and the connection pool is timing out.
The datasource is the default `hikari datasource` configured by Spring Boot (this works correctly with Write Through).

[image]

**Ignite Cache Configuration**

```
 CacheConfiguration<Long, Customer> customerWriteAheadCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<(CacheName.WRITE_AHEAD.getCacheName());
 customerWriteAheadCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Customer.class);
 customerWriteAheadCacheCfg.setWriteThrough(true);
 customerWriteAheadCacheCfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
 customerWriteAheadCacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
 customerWriteAheadCacheCfg.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
 customerWriteAheadCacheCfg.setWriteBehindBatchSize(50);
```

**Store and Entity Configuration**

```
CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Long, Customer> customerPojoFactory1 = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<>();
customerPojoFactory1.setDataSourceBean("dataSource");
customerPojoFactory1.setDialect(new BasicJdbcDialect());
JdbcType customerPojoType1 = new JdbcType();
customerPojoType1.setCacheName(CacheName.WRITE_AHEAD.getCacheName());
customerPojoType1.setKeyType(Long.class);
customerPojoType1.setValueType(Customer.class);
customerPojoType1.setDatabaseTable("customer");
customerPojoType1.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "id", Long.class, "id"));
customerPojoType1.setValueFields(
           new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "name", String.class, "name"),
           new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "type", String.class, "type")
);
customerPojoFactory1.setTypes(customerPojoType1);
```

For the benchmark, I'm just using `put` in the cache

```
public void saveToCacheWriteAhead(Customer customer) {
    waCache.put(customer.getId(), customer);
}
```

Any idea on what might be causing the error ?

Comment: Please show the connection pool configuration

Comment: There is no explicit connection pool configuration, the `datasource` bean is the default one that Spring Boot sets up with Spring Data (wiz Hikari CP, default pool size is  [10](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)).

Comment: Check that a connection could be established by calling context.getBean("datasource").getConnection()

Comment: Yes, the `datasource` bean is working correctly. Spring Data Jpa is using it correctly, and I finally resorted to providing a custom `CacheStoreAdapter` using the datasource. With the custom persistence class, write ahead is working correctly. Not sure why Ignite's inbuilt write-ahead is problematic with the datasource bean.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection is not available" could mean that the connection pool is full.
In case of write ahead a connection is opened within each writing thread.
Thus the max number of connections should be at least the number of writing threads.

Comment: For my test, there is only one thread that is writing to the cache, and default pool size of Hikari CP is 10.